# Login problems: Authentication autowired controller issue Apache Netbeans Java

Tags: java, spring

I'm constructing a Login with java, I've been following a tutorial but now I've encountered an issue. The app is supposed to be working and I should be able to try it on postman, but it is failing to start.
The issue is:

`Description:`

Field passwordEncoder in com.portfolio.anamorujaportfolio.Security.Controller.AuthController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could
The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' in your configuration.

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package com.portfolio.anamorujaportfolio.Security.Controller;

import com.portfolio.anamorujaportfolio.Security.Dto.JwtDto;
import com.portfolio.anamorujaportfolio.Security.Dto.LoginUsuario;
import com.portfolio.anamorujaportfolio.Security.Dto.NuevoUsuario;
import com.portfolio.anamorujaportfolio.Security.Entity.Rol;
import com.portfolio.anamorujaportfolio.Security.Entity.Usuario;
import com.portfolio.anamorujaportfolio.Security.Enums.RolNombre;
import com.portfolio.anamorujaportfolio.Security.Service.RolService;
import com.portfolio.anamorujaportfolio.Security.Service.UsuarioService;
import com.portfolio.anamorujaportfolio.Security.jwt.JwtProvider;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@CrossOrigin
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    UsuarioService usuarioService;
    @Autowired
    RolService rolService;
    @Autowired
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    
    @PostMapping("/nuevo")
    public ResponseEntity<?> nuevo(@Valid @RequestBody NuevoUsuario nuevoUsuario, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Campos mal puestos o email invalido"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        
        if(usuarioService.existsByNombreUsuario(nuevoUsuario.getNombreUsuario()))
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Ese nombre de usuario ya existe"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        
         if(usuarioService.existsByEmail(nuevoUsuario.getEmail()))
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Ese email ya existe"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
         
         Usuario usuario = new Usuario(nuevoUsuario.getNombre(), nuevoUsuario.getNombreUsuario(), nuevoUsuario.getEmail(), passwordEncoder.encode(nuevoUsuario.getPassword()));
         Set<Rol>roles=new HashSet<>();
         roles.add(rolService.getByRolNombre(RolNombre.ROLE_USER).get());
         
         if(nuevoUsuario.getRoles().contains("admin"))
             roles.add(rolService.getByRolNombre(RolNombre.ROLE_ADMIN).get());
         usuario.setRoles(roles);
         usuarioService.save(usuario);
         
         return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Usuario guardado"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<JwtDto> login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginUsuario loginUsuario, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Campos mal puestos"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginUsuario.getNombreUsuario(),loginUsuario.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        
        String jwt = jwtProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        
        JwtDto jwtDto = new JwtDto(jwt, userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
        return new ResponseEntity(jwtDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }   
    
}
```

```
It's my first go at Java, thanks in advance for the help!! 

I've no idea, but I want it to run
```

Comment: The error message is very clear about the action to take - `Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' in your configuration`. This question - [Spring Boot - bean definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218985/spring-boot-bean-definition), should help in how to define a bean.

Comment: Thanks @Chaosfire for the help. I've put  (at)Bean
    (at)Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder; but it doesnt seem to help. it just says: annotation interface not applicable to this kind of declaration.  also on the mainsecurity.java 
    (at)Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
 but still doesn't work :/

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74262161/edit) question to show attempts, don't put it in comments. Also, `still doesn't work` does not mean anything, same error? other error? explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -2):

The error says it all. Basically the application thinks that a configuration is missing which is unable to bind the PasswordEncoder.

Upon closer look, PasswordEncoder is part of the Spring package and the way AutoInjections work is (by default), spring only scans the classes from the root package and since its not part of the root it cant autowire the bean.

You can initialise it like this from a custom config class and annotate it as a Bean and then Autowire it..

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Please refer an implementation here
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt
Please refer to the documentation here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html#authentication-password-storage
Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not good idea, this will create new instances of `PasswordEncoder` every time it's used. Just declare it as a bean.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).